# Using perl Regular expressions I want to make sure a number comes in order

Tags: regex, perl

I want to use a regular expression to check a string to make sure 4 and 5 are in order.  I thought I could do this by doing

```
'$string =~ m/.45./'
```

I think I am going wrong somewhere. I am very new to Perl. I would honestly like to put it in an array and search through it and find out that way, but I'm assuming there is a much easier way to do it with regex.

```
print "input please:\n";
$input = <STDIN>;
chop($input);
if ($input =~ m/45/ and $input =~ m/5./) {
    print "works";
}
else {
    print "nata";
}
```

EDIT: Added Info
I just want 4 and 5 in order, but if 5 comes before at all say 322195458900023 is the number then where 545 is a problem 5 always have to come right after 4.

Comment: It isn't clear to me if you are looking for 4 followed immediately by 5 or followed by 5 after any number of characters? For example would "4ethr5" be a match? How about "4wte5weer4"?

Comment: I just want 4 and 5 in order, but if 5 comes before at all say 322195458900023 is the number then where 545 is a problem 5 always have to come after 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to match any string that contains two digits where the first digit is smaller than the second:

There is an obscure feature called "postponed regular expressions". We can include code inside a regular expression with

```
(??{CODE})
```

and the value of that code is interpolated into the regex.

The special *verb* `(*FAIL)` makes sure that the match fails (in fact only the current branch). We can combine this into following one-liner:

```
perl -ne'print /(\d)(\d)(??{$1<$2 ? "" : "(*FAIL)"})/ ? "yes\n" :"no\n"'
```

It prints `yes` when the current line contains two digits where the first digit is smaller than the second digit, and `no` when this is not the case.

The regex explained:

```
m{
   (\d)   # match a number, save it in $1
   (\d)   # match another number, save it in $2
   (??{   # start postponed regex
      $1 < $2      # if $1 is smaller than $2
      ? ""         # then return the empty string (i.e. succeed)
      : "(*FAIL)"  # else return the *FAIL verb
   })     # close postponed regex
}x;       # /x modifier so I could use spaces and comments
```

However, this is a bit advanced and masochistic; using an array is (1) far easier to understand, and (2) probably better anyway. But it is still possible using only regexes.

---

#### Edit

Here is a way to make sure that no `5` is followed by a `4`:

```
/^(?:[^5]+|5(?=[^4]|$))*$/
```

This reads as: The string is composed from any number (zero or more) characters that are *not* a five, or a five that is followed by either a character that is not a four or the five is the end of the string.

This regex is also a possibility:

```
/^(?:[^45]+|45)*$/
```

it allows any characters in the string that are not `4` or `5`, or the sequence `45`. I.e., there are no single `4`s or `5`s allowed.

Comment: I like this method and it's quite impressive.  I will be noting it down.

Comment: @KirsKringle Edited my question, now fulfills your requirements. Your test number `322195458900023` does not pass.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to match all 5 and search fails, where preceded is not 4:

```
if( $str =~ /(?<!4)5/ ) {
    #Fail
}
```